# python : meaning of if not (p%q):

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

I got this is code from a paper.

I would like to know meaning of:

```
if not (p%q)

x = 0
p = 2
while(p<7):
  q=2
  while(q<p):
    if not (p%q):q=p
    q+=1
  if(q>p):x+=p
  p+=1
print(x)`
```

Comment: See the two answers from krmogi and j1-lee.  I greatly prefer to write `if p%q == 0` instead of `if not (p%q)`.  The former is easy to read, the latter is needlessly clever.  When you're doing math, write a math expression; when you're doing logic, write a logic expression.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `not (p % q)` is equivalent to `p % q == 0`.

For numbers, zero is "falsy" and all others are "truthy": https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth. Therefore, we have

"`p % q == 0`" iff (i.e., if and only if) "`p % q is False`" iff "`not (p % q) is True`".

Therefore, `if p % q == 0:` is equivalent to `if not (p % q) is True:`, which is in turn equivalent to `if not (p % q):`, since `is True` part can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially saying `if True` (If the modulo == 0). The modulo sign (%) gets the remainder of a division. The modulo operator(%) is considered an arithmetic operation. So since it is doing `2/2`, we get a modulo of 0. Now the statement is `if not 0:`.

That being said, there are truthy and falsy values in Python:

Values that evaluate to False are considered Falsy. Values that evaluate to True are considered Truthy.

Some truthy values include:

- Non-empty sequences or collections
- Numeric values that are not zero.

Some falsy values include:

- Zero of any numeric type.
- Empty sequences or collections
- None and False

So the code now translates `if not False:` (If the modulo != 0), which is the same as `if True` (If the modulo == 0).